# bootstrap-select.js & Laravel Form Facade -- no select "value"

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-select

When using bootstrap-select.js in combination with the Laravel Form facade, no value is transmitted. `dd()` says null

`{!! Form::select('user', $users, null, array('class' => 'selectpicker show-tick', 'data-live-search' => 'true', 'id' => 'user_select')) !!}`

However when using the form facade without bootstrap-select like this:

`{!! Form::select('user', $users, null) !!}`

it works.

`dd()` says 1

Comment: What have you `dd()` ?

Comment: `dd($request->user);`

Comment: Check your form post back, i assume the id => value sets the selected user? Perhaps something is wrong there.

Comment: `$users = User::all()->pluck('realname', 'id');
        return view('shop.devices.add')->with('users', $users);` this is how i do it. seems about right because in the generated HTML it is displayed as `<option value="$id">$realname</option>`

Comment: @Scarwolf please inspect the page with the browser to see how the html is formed. Also, try `dd($request-all())`

Comment: Here's the output @Alejandro http://pastebin.com/L21JLegb

Comment: @Scarwolf ok, the html seems ok but the field isn't even sent in the request. Your `<select>` is within a `<form>`, right?

Comment: Yes. Right before `{!! Form::token() !!}` and `{!! Form::submit() !!}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using bootstrap select, You should fetch the input like:

```
Input::get('id_of_your_input');
```

and when not using bootstrap select you should do it like this:

```
Input::get('name_of_your_input');
```

Coz bootstrap select creates another input to be sent with a new name (extracted from the original Input's Id)
:)

**Update**
You can use `dd(Input::all())` to see all the inputs sent to your controller with their names.

Comment: Oh! I'm fetching using `Request $request` so `$request->user`. Is it possible to fetch the name like this without `Input::`?

Comment: Well `dd(Input::get('user_select'));` still says `null`. This is how I have my select currently: `{!! Form::select('user', $users, null, array('class' => ' show-tick', 'data-live-search' => 'true', 'id' => 'user_select')) !!}`

Comment: Try `dd(Input::all())`, So that you can see all inputs sent to your controller along with their names. :)

Comment: Here's the output: http://pastebin.com/L21JLegb As i thought, the select is not sent

Answer (score 0):

Simplest reproduction of your case:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.11.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.11.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

{!! Form::open() !!}
    <select class="selectpicker show-tick" data-live-search="true" name="user">
        <option value="1">Marvin Test</option>
        <option value="2">Lorem Ipsum</option>
        <option value="3">Amy Johnson</option>
        <option value="4">sdsd</option>
        <option value="5">lol lol</option>
        <option value="6">test test</option>
    </select>
    {!! Form::submit() !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

`dd($request->all()` gives:

```
array:2 [▼
  "_token" => "GPsRkSn3GVK3zWZmJ2Rf7rQlZ75WVZ2c1JxHZgjy"
  "user" => "6"
]
```

The token hidden field is automatically added. That's why I asked in the comment if you are between `Form::open` and `Form::close`

Comment: I removed `Form::token()`. but still, user not transferred. Is this because of `Form::select()` in combination with bootstrap-select maybe? How can I do that better with an array of users?

Comment: ok, I tried writing the select in the easiest way possible: http://pastebin.com/RRXUdNnh even there, no data is sent... ._.

Comment: @Scarwolf the HTML you pasted first was taken from the page source or actually inspected with the browser the current state of the dom?